# How do I disable the "Space" Key on the keyboard in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

I'm creating a login system and I don't want spaces to be allowed in the username field. Instead of check and validating the field, I want to prevent spaces from being added.

So, every time the user presses the spacebar, nothing should happen. How can I do that? 
I've seen Instagram do this.

This is my code so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var signUp: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var navBar: UINavigationBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var UsernameText: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

             self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
        UsernameText.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"TypeYourUsername",
            attributes:[NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()])

        func textField(UsernameText: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if (string == " ") {
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        UsernameText.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Override `UITextField` delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. And in that method check for space character. If found than return false.

Note: Don't forget to set delegate for textfield.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (string == " ") {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**Edit: More Code**

```
class ViewController : UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textField : UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textField.delegate = self
    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if (string == " ") {
          return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Here `textField` object is an IBOutlet. It means that text field control is in storyboard and connected with this variable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But still doesn't work, I paste the code above in my question. The space Key is still make spaces in the twext field. Thank you again @Kampai

Comment: this still allows you to paste in spaces.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4.1/4.2/5.0/5.1/5.2**

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string == " " {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 2.0

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let whitespaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()
    let range = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(whitespaceSet)
    if let _ = range {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**In Swift 2.1**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let whitespaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()
    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(whitespaceSet) {
       return false
       }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3**

```
class SignUpViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

lazy var emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let tf = UITextField()
    tf.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tf.placeholder = "Email address"
    tf.delegate = self
    return tf
}()

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let whitespaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaces

    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: whitespaceSet) {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return true
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let whitespaceSet = CharacterSet.whitespaces
    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: whitespaceSet) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return string != " "
}
```

This is the most easy to understand syntax for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the User tapped on space key and neglect it with the following logic. But I think you cannot disable the button itself.

```swift
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
  string != " "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.1**

**Just simple with Single line of code you can stop whitespace**

**For All Textfield**

```
 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        textField.text = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        return true
    }
```

**For Single  Textfield**

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == txtid
    {
        textField.text = textField.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can disable WhiteSpaces until Your (First character )text enter. (some improvement )

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let whitespaceSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaces
        let range = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: whitespaceSet)
        if let _ = range {
            let text = textField.text ?? ""
            if text.isBlankByTrimming || text.isEmpty {
                return false
            }else {
               return true
            }
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }
```

Here u can use this Extension to trim white spaces .(even when u are checking your validations )
  using above textfield Delegate you can disable whitespaces but if have string like this

```
 Example : "MyName Surname             "
```

so can trim end spaces also before saving this data.

```
    extension String {
        var isBlankByTrimming: Bool {
            let trimmed = self.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            return trimmed.isEmpty
        } 
       func trimWhitespacesAndNewlines() -> String{
              return self.trimmingCharacters(in: 
                                CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
        }
     }
```

for use ::

```
let yourString = "MyName Surname          " 
let finalString = yourString.trimWhitespacesAndNewlines()
```